# Synchronizing on an int, long, or String value, as well as AND/OR options?

Tags: java, concurrency

This is a little bit of a combo question:

1. Let's say I have multiple threads that need to lock on values such as a user ID.  For example, I want to isolate database operations related to a given player, so that operations related to ID 5 could be run simultaneously alongside operations on ID 7, but if an operation on ID 5 is running, another operation on ID 5 would have to wait.  I have previously used code from this example: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/04/java-synchronizing-on-transient-id.html but would like something that is core to Java and may use generics to easily allow this to be used with other data types such as ints or longs.
2. How would I optionally lock on two of these kinds of variables, with AND or OR logic?  For example, let's say I have a messaging system where clients can message each other, but I want to have threads block on either ID?  In other words, if I want to do an operation between IDs 5 and 7, I want to wait for any running operations on EITHER 5 or 7 to finish first before unlocking.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Strings aren't primitives. And the Longs and Integers used by generics aren't really either.

Comment: What Sb said.  And I suspect you misunderstand the purpose and nature of synchronizing if you're wanting to do it on a primitive type.

Comment: Removed references to "primitive" in my post.  Sorry if I was misusing the semantics of the term.  Consider that I'm using this to synchronize access to a database where the locking needs to be done on something like a row ID.  In the Java code, this value would be transient, and there's no unique Java object I can synchronize on.

Comment: The problem is that it's not sufficient to lock on the same VALUE.  You must lock on the SAME OBJECT.  If you take an int and convert it to an Integer, eg, you've (potentially) got a different object vs the same int value converted to Integer in another thread -- so locking will be useless.

Comment: Yep, I understand that.  That's the problem addressed by the link I posted: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/04/java-synchronizing-on-transient-id.html  I have used this and it seems to work as advertised, but was hoping to find something that's easily adaptable to other data types, or maybe there's a newer, core Java feature that does this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: The database should already provide transaction isolation. You don't need belt and braces.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything like that myself but I would build a hashtable that maps the id's to `Lock`s. The fact that id's are primitives shouldn't be a problem, you can use the `Integer` or `Long` variants for keys in your hashtable.

More info about [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html)'s